# Django Channels - Real time Notifications

Tags: django, websocket, notifications, real-time, django-channels

Suppose, if user is online, websocket connection is created and user will get all the realtime notification.

But, if user went offline, websocket connection breaks, then if any realtime notification has to be delivered during offline period, will it be again delivered if user comes online again(means when websocket connection is made again of that user)??

Answer (score 0):

depends on the way you set up your channels. Once the client has closed the socket you can not send messages to it, so unless you setup permanent storage(be it cache/file/db) where those messages land if no peer is on the other end you will loose them

Comment: By default, where does Django channels stores the notification data, if not delivered?

Comment: i believe it uses a caching module like redis to handle the message queues, but it is up to you to install/configure it. Nonetheless it is a real-time communication, anything beyond that(repeaters, delivery confirmation, client states management) is up to you. Channels are a nice starting point, that wraps the sockets, but do not consider it off-the-shelf solution.